# How can I make my binary file is served as binary and not text when user choose "Save Linked File As..." in Safari?

Tags: apache, safari, ubuntu

I'm serving a binary file (.IPA) with `Ubuntu/Apache 2.2`.
When I have chosen `Save Linked File As...` in Safari, it says it's text file. And it guides me to add `.txt` extension. However it does not add any extra extension when I download it just clicking link.

I added line `AddType application/octet-stream .ipa` in apache configuration file. I don't know what's wrong with this. Is this a bug of Safari or my misconfiguration? (1) If it caused by bug, how can I avoid this? (2) Or if it caused by misconfiguration, what should I do?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a Safari bug. If your is is sending the right ContentType header so that it saves when normally clicked, I can't see how it wouldn't be sending the same header when the browser requests it through it's little save file mechanism. Have you searched around to see if Safari user forums have any complains about this behavior in general?

Comment: @Caleb I realized I have to do anything to avoid this even it caused by Safari bug.... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Eonil I understand your situation but chasing the Safari bug might lead you to somebody who has found a workaround. BTW, have you tested this in other browsers to see what their behavior is?

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try to track Safari bug to find something. I didn't tested Chrome, and it downloaded the file with no problem.

Comment: I would also check Firefox, Opera, and anything else you come across just to see if there is any inconsistency with your server. You might also use something like Firebug to look at the headers that get served when the file is downloaded via a direct hit vs a download-save-as type command.

Comment: The octet-stream line should be working for you, so make sure you've edited the correct config file, the correct portion of the file, etc. Also make sure that you're restarting Apache after you make these changes to ensure the new configuration is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by Safari's behaviour and can be avoided by using JavaScript to disable context menus:

```
var browser = navigator.userAgent;
if (browser.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > 0)
{
    var allLinks = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
        allLinks[i].oncontextmenu = function() { return false };
    }
}
```

Comment: This just degrades usability, does not solve or avoid the problem.

Comment: Unless you convince Safari users to change their browser, or Apple to adjust the behaviour then you'll need to decide whether to disable context menus for links in Safari or educate users to remove the .txt suffix for unknown filetypes. Its not possible to have your cake and eat it in this situation. This solution just stops the context menu (the method of triggering this unwanted download behaviour) in Safari browsers.